# ASP.NET WebForms GetVirtualPath always returns null

Tags: asp.net-4.0, asp.net-routing

I am just getting introduced to ASP.NET routing and have two routes registered at the moment:

```
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "default",
            "{Path}/{Name}.aspx{Query}",
            "~/Default.aspx",
            true,
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "Name", "default" } },
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "Name", @"[-_\w]+" } });

        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "home",
            "{Name}.aspx{Query}",
            "~/Default.aspx",
            true,
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "Name", "default" } },
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "Name", @"[-_\w]+" } });
```

However, when I try to build urls using these routes, I always get an exception. I tried this:

```
private string GetVirtualPath(RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(
    null, values).VirtualPath;
}
```

and also this:

```
private string GetVirtualPath(RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(
        new RequestContext(wrapper,
          RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(wrapper)), 
              values).VirtualPath;
}
```

Either way, I get a null reference exception on `RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath` when I call:

```
GetVirtualPath(new RouteValueDictionary { { "Name", entity.Name } });
```

Or even:

```
GetVirtualPath(new RouteValueDictionary { { "Name", entity.Name }, { "Query", string.Empty } });
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own question. The problem was with my route restrictions. Once I removed the lines with `new RouteValueDictionary { { "Name", @"[-_\w]+" } }` everything started working.